# How to close mongodb idle connection(active: false)?

Tags: mongodb

I have an application running on node and using the mongodb library to establish connection and closing it. But the problem is, from the mongo serverStatus() command i can see that there is still 2k+ current connections still available.

```
> db.serverStatus().connections
{ "current" : 2993, "available" : 835867, "totalCreated" : 220841 }
```

and most of it are having the `active: false` status.

My questions is, is there a way for me to force close these idle connections which after some time will affect my application with an timeout error.

I tried using the `killOp()` command but these only works if there is still opid value listed in these idle connections.

Appreciate some feedback on how can handle this kind of situations.

Answer (score 3):

This can be avoided by setting up the [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) parameter of [Connection Pool Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-pool-options)

> This maxIdleTimeMS parameter sets the maximum number of milliseconds
>   that a connection can remain idle in the pool before being removed and
>   closed.

Set this parameter as per your requirement. So the idle connections will be closed once the time limit exceeds.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Our Dev team are looking into the application driver that are initiating these mongo connection.

Comment: @NazmilBINNORDDIN Are you able to resolve the issue?